# Extend spree to have functionalities as Shopify?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, e-commerce, spree

I'm new to spree. I'm not sure whether is that possible to extend spree to have a functionality like Shopify. The user signups to create a store. He owns everything to that store. Each owner is not able to edit other stores.

How can I extend it? Which is the best strategy?

- through database sharding, each store has it own database, connect to different based on domain name?
- add store_id to every table, that would need to change a lot of code, right?

Any ideas?

Answer (score 4):

You can have a look at this official extension:
https://github.com/spree/spree-multi-domain
This extension allows you to have multiple stores on multiple domains using the same backend.